# strange behaviour of procmail when piping content to c++ executable

Tags: c++, piping, procmail

I have a working procmail config.
this is the rc.filters :

```
:0 w :a.lock
* ^From:(.*\<)?(try@gmail\.com)\>
| $HOME/executable/a.out
```

this file compiles and works, procmail delivers the mail,
and the executable writes the content to the output file.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("output.txt");

    string line;
    while (getline(cin, line)) 
    {
    myfile << line << endl;     
    }    
myfile.close();    
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

the problem is I need a cin object with the content to pass
to a constructor of the [Mimetic](http://www.codesink.org/mimetic_mime_library.html) library.
I need this executable to work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <mimetic/mimetic.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace mimetic;

int main(void)
{
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("output.txt");

MimeEntity me(cin);                         
const Header& h = me.header();  
string subjectString = h.subject();
myfile << subjectString;
myfile << "Check";      
myfile.close();
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If I take a Mime message called message.txt and do the following with the second code :

```
cat message.txt | ./a.out

./a.out < message.txt
```

In both cases the executable works and I get the subject in an output.txt
but for some when it is invoked and the content piped by procmail it doesn't work,
and all I get in the output.txt is "Check" which means that the file
was at least invoked.

the procmail.log states that everything is fine.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks. Yes I did try the example on the mimetic site. same thing, works great when I try from the console, and doesn't with procmail piping. another thing is that when I try procmail with a shell script it also works. something with the way procmail pipes...

Comment: What's the value of your `SHELL`?  Do things improve if you add `SHELL=/bin/sh` to the top of your `.procmailrc`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's going on exactly but I would capture the input from `std::cin` into a string and then pass a `std::istringstream` constructed from that value to `MimeEntity`. This way you can inspect what the input from `std::cin` was while still having it processed by the library:

```
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> begin(std::cin), end;
std::string message(begin, end);
out << "received >>>" << message << "<<<\n";
std::istringstream in(message);
MimeEntity me(in);
// ...
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion. when invoked with procmail the part before the MimeEntity is printed to the output file. but the parsed content of MimeEntity isn't. when I try from the console everything is printed. are there any other ways to "reconstruct" a cin like object ?

Comment: @Stasv: This description implies that the pipe is _not_ the problem. Instead, something in the program's environment is setup by procmail to put your `MimeEntity` off. I would check if `MimeEntity` uses some environment variables which are set up differently (e.g., the locale or the encoding), if there is a dependency on the user (e.g. run the program as the user procmail from the console), etc.

Comment: Thanks! would you happen to know how would I go about checking the user and the environment variables from with in code?

Comment: @Stasv: Finding out about the user depends on the operating system. On UNIXes you'd use `getuid()`. It is almost certainly just run as procmail's user. You might be able to run it as your user by setting the setuid bit (`chmod u+s a.out`). The standard library only has functions to inspect the environment (e.g., `getenv()`) while the shell provides `printenv`. You could run a shell-script from procmail which dumps the result of `printenv` to a suitable file.

Comment: I've piped the content to a shell script and found that the user that is running it is the user the mail is being sent to. just a normal user account.when I run the executable as that user it works OK. the printenv outputs for console vs procmail for that user are quite different. LANG=en_US.UTF-8 appears in the working env , there's a SHELLFLAGS=-c in the non-working env, the PATH variables are a bit different, and the other things seem irrelevant

Comment: I've tried running the whole thing when invoked by a cron job. it also works. this is the cron printenv : MAILTO=root SHELL=/bin/bash USER=root PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin _=/usr/bin/printenv PWD=/ SHLVL=3 HOME=/ LOGNAME=root ...